# Can Selenium use buttons from LightSwitch librarz?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-lightswitch

Can Selenium use LightSwitch buttons?

At first I had to locate button, the LightSwitch is a button written in CSS, then I will use By.CSSSelector to find.
But after I found the button, check which form it is using if on tap/click etc., I found that it is `vclick` from Jquery library.

Then I wrote code:

```
js.ExecuteScript("$('.ui-page-active .msls-footer div div:nth-child(2) span').trigger('vclick')");
```

But even I find the button using selenium yet it is not being clicked.
Am I missing something here?

Another thing is that, test will pass correctly, but there is no window opened, after clicking.

Application should switch on click to a new screen, but it really doesn't want to do this move.

Screen of button location:

[image: Screen of button location]

After click expected screen:

[image: After click expected screen]

Comment: Why is it not being clicked??? is there any exception?? share your html as well...

Comment: I dunno know why it isn´t clicked, but test will start after debbug correctly, without error,open the lightswitch html page and click action will don´t provide expected action which is opening another lightswitch screen. But test will pass as correct.

Comment: could you share your HTML or website url??

Comment: I can share it, but I am not absolutly sure if it will be usefull and it is just testing api before, adding tests to main project. Then it is not on server, but in local(computer).                                                        http://localhost:51413/HTMLClient/                                                                      And main thing is that, because it is core lightswitch based API, it has not classic html page.

Comment: Ok share html source with inspector pressing f12..

Comment: I don´t understand how can I post it to you, that code is too long for classic  comment and inspector will don´t make it possible or I don´t know how to use inspector for sharing html sources, unless that I will save it to my computer and sent these sources via mail.

Comment: Ok once try as `IWebElement el = js.ExecuteScript("return $('.ui-page-active .msls-footer div div:nth-child(2) span')");el.Click();`.. and let me know

Comment: IWebElement el = (IWebElement)js.ExecuteScript("return $                   ('.ui-page-active .msls-footer div div:nth-child(2)')[0]");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            el.Click();                                                                                               The way to go, in lightswitch is something for what I have to w8 before I will be able to do another action, right now I am trzing to find out on what >D

Comment: But anyway thx for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to use `WebDriverWait` instead of `Thread.Sleep()` as below :-

```
IWebElement el = (IWebElement)js.ExecuteScript("return $ ('.ui-page-active .msls-footer div div:nth-child(2)')[0]");

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(el)).Click();
```

Hope it will work..:)

Comment: Saurabh. Thx for a help your method is right and works without problems.